# Select Max DATE Record Without using a correlated subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, max

I have two different databases (not just two different tables). I need select the `Max(Date)` from one `database.table` while joining another `database.table`.

In my below example, I would like to return

```
+-------------+-----------+-------------+
| CompanyKey  | JobDate   | CompanyName |
+-------------+-----------+-------------+
|           1 | 1/10/2020 | Alpha Co    |
+-------------+-----------+-------------+
```

My modifying this statement:

```
SELECT  rj.*, oc.CompanyName
FROM    Resources.Jobs rj  
JOIN    Organizations.Company oc ON oc.CompanyKey = rj.CompanyKey
WHERE   rj.CompanyKey = '1'
```

Adding

```
 AND MAX(rj.JobDate)
```

Returns the ***Error code 1111, invalid use of group function***.

I thought about doing a LEFT JOIN according to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) but since I am already doing a JOIN to grab the company name, I was unsure how to go about combing my two JOIN clauses.

Any help?

Table Structure

```
Resources.Jobs
+------------+-----------+
| CompanyKey |  JobDate  |
+------------+-----------+
|          1 | 1/10/2020 |
|          1 | 1/9/2020  |
|          1 | 1/8/2020  |
|          2 | 1/10/2020 |
+------------+-----------+

Organizations.Company
+------------+-------------+
| CompanyKey | CompanyName |
+------------+-------------+
|          1 | Alpha Co    |
|          2 | Beta Co     |
+------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `GROUP BY` clause so you can use an aggregate function (such as `MAX()`), where all non-aggregated columns should appear:

```
select oc.CompanyKey, max(rj.JobDate) JobDate, oc.CompanyName
from Resources.Jobs rj  
inner join Organizations.Company oc ON oc.CompanyKey = rj.CompanyKey
where rj.CompanyKey = 1
group by oc.CompanyKey, oc.CompanyName
```

Comment: Hmmmm this returns the oldest record. Actually, its the first record for this company.

Answer (score 0):

one possible approach is to join to an inline view that gets one job date per company key, something like this:

```
 SELECT ...
      , m.max_job_date
      , ...  
   FROM t

   LEFT
   JOIN (
          SELECT j.companykey
               , MAX(j.jobdate) AS max_job_date
            FROM Resources.Jobs j
           GROUP
              BY j.companykey
        ) m
     ON m.companykey = t.companykey
```

The inline view query (derived table) `m` can be run separately. In the context of the outer query, the inline view works like a table.